# Dynamically update field in web2py SQLFORM

Tags: python, web2py

Using an example close to the one from the many to many relationship example in the book:

```
db = DAL("sqlites://storage.sqlite")

db.define_table('persons',
                    Field('name'))

db.define_table('things',
                    Field('name'))

db.define_table('ownership',
                    Field('person', 'reference persons'),
                    Field('thing', 'reference things'))
```

I have an additional table :

```
db.define_table('usages',
                    Field('person', 'reference person',requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.person.id, '%(name)s'),
                    Field('thing', 'reference thing'),
                    Field('usage'))
```

For the table `usages` I want to have dropdown menus for both `person` and `thing` fields hence the use of `requires ....`.
However I would like to have the dropdown menu from `thing` to changes according to the selection in `person` (to limit the choice to things a person owns).
I thought about using `requires` as i did to get the dropdown menu, however I cannot use `db.usages.person` in a `requires = IS_IN_DB(...)` because the entry is not created and therefore it throws an exception.

What I tried :
`requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db((db.usages.person == db.persons.id) &(db.persons.id == db.ownership.person) &(db.ownership.person == db.things.name)))`

Using `requires = IS_IN_DB(db,db.things.id, '%(name)s')` gives me a dropdown menu for `thing` but it lists all of the them regardless of the selection in `person`.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do what you want. You will need to use Javascript to (a) detect when a selection is made in the `person` field, and (b) make an Ajax request to the server to fetch a list of options for the `thing` select element.

For some examples, check out [these posts](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/search?q=cascading+drop) on the web2pyslices site, and also check out [`plugin_lazy_options_widget`](https://github.com/kenji4569/sqlabs/blob/master/modules/plugin_lazy_options_widget.py).

Also, regarding your code:

```
requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db((db.usages.person == db.persons.id) &(db.persons.id == db.ownership.person) &(db.ownership.person == db.things.name)))
```

note, that the second argument to `IS_IN_DB` must be a Field object or field name, not a DAL Set object. If you want to limit the set of options via a filter, the *first* argument can be a Set object (though, as noted, that won't help in this case, as you don't know what the filter criterion will be until a selection is made in the browser).

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative feedback. I must admit I am a bit disappointed, I was hoping for an obvious answer that eluded me. I've never used Javascript until now, I suppose it's time to dive in.

Comment: I added links to some examples and a widget plugin that may work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.